# Testing Grails App Generating pdf file Cannot get property 'config' on null object

Tags: java, grails, integration-testing

I am trying to test a service class that will generate a pdf file but this error occurs:

> [getDocument] EXCEPTION: variables: [input, input, input], message:
>   Cannot get property 'config' on null object

My Service class is:

```
class TemplateService {

    static transactional = false
    def grailsApplication

    def getDocument(inputs, idTemp) {
        def result
        if(inputs) {
            long dateBeginTransaction = System.currentTimeMillis()

            try {
                def http = new HTTPBuilder(grailsApplication.config.tempdoc.url?.replace("COI", idTemp))
                http.auth.basic grailsApplication.config.rest.login, grailsApplication.config.rest.password

                http.request(POST,JSON) { req ->
                    headers.'Accept' = 'application/json'
                    headers.'Content-type' = 'application/json'
                    body = [
                        inputs: inputs
                    ]
                    response.success = { resp, json ->
                        log.info "[getDocument] time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - dateBeginTransaction) / 1000 + " ms"
                        result = json?.pdf
                    }

                    response.failure = { resp, reader ->
                        log.error "[getDocument] inputs: " + inputs + ", response: " + resp + ", message: " + reader?.message
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error "[getDocument] EXCEPTION: inputs: " + inputs + ", message: " + e.message
            }
        } else {
            log.error "[getDocument] params sense valors"
        }
        result
    }
}
```

This is my Test:
*Note inputs is an arraylist

```
void "generate document"() {
    given: "generate document"
        def TemplateService = new TemplateService()

    when:
        def result = TemplateService.getDocument(inputs, idTemp)

    then:
        result != null
        result.size() > 0   

    where:
       inputs = [ "input", "input", "input"]
        idTemp =  "12AD"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you'll have to mock the config in your test. In Grails 3.3.5:

```
class PlaServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<Plaservice>, DataTest {

    Closure doWithConfig() {{ config ->
        config.plantidoc.url = 'my url'
    }}

    void "generate document"() {
        given:
            def variables = ["input:input", "input:input"]
            def idPlantitlla = "12AD"

        when:
            def result = service.getDocument(variables, idPlantitlla)

        then:
            // test the result
    }
}
```

Comment: a just mock it but same error:   def setup() {
         grailsApplication.config.plantidoc.url = 'my url '

    }

    def cleanup() {
    }


    void "generate document"() {
        given: "generate document"
            def plaservice = new Plaservice()
            plantidocService.grailsApplication = grailsApplication

        when:
            def result = plaservice.getDocument(variables, idPlantitlla)

       
        where:
           variables = ["input:input", "input:input"]
            idPlantitlla =  "12AD"
    }

Comment: which version of grails are you using?

Comment: grailsVersion=3.3.5.

Comment: can i contack you or can you cantact me: broganzquinto@gmail.com

Comment: I tried your code but an error persist: Test worker] cat.dipta.mfi.PlantidocService           : [getDocument] EXCEPTION: variables: [numeroExpedient:numeroExpedient, actuacio:actuacio, fase:fase], message: Cannot get property 'config' on null object

Answer (score 0):

you can make your test an Integration Test (move it to test/integration-test folder) and in this way grailsApplication will be injected into your service